# Selecting approximately regular samples from an irregularly spaced vector

Tags: python, numpy

This is my problem, suppose I have a vector like this:

```
import numpy as np
idxx = np.array([0.        , 0.07665982, 0.24366872, 0.49555099, 0.74743326,
       1.07871321, 1.58247775, 2.24503765, 2.58179329, 3.16221766,
       3.74811773, 4.1615332 , 4.58042437, 5.33059548])
```

I am interested in filtering out only those values which are *approximately* multiples of `0.25`, `0.5` and `1.0`. Let's start with `0.25` to demonstrate what I am looking the filter to return:

```
np.array([0.24366872, 0.49555099, 0.74743326,
       1.07871321, 1.58247775, 2.24503765, 2.58179329,
       3.74811773, 4.58042437, 5.33059548])
```

Here only values that are approximately some multiple of `0.25` remain. In practise, I will also need to keep the first entry `0.0`, but have removed it for this demonstration.

If I am using `0.5` then my result would look like this:

```
np.array([0.49555099, 1.07871321, 1.58247775, 2.58179329, 4.58042437])
```

My initial attempts was:

```
import math
for i in idxx:
    g = 0.25
    k = i % g
    if math.isclose(k, g, rel_tol=0.5):
        print('This is reasonably close: ', i, '\n\t for modulus k == ', k, '\n')
```

Still requires me to do an awful lot of tuning (and I still cannot manage to filter out what I want), so I wondering if anyone has a better way of doing this properly?

In essence, I want to select those irregular points (e.g. 0.24366872), onto a "regularly" spaced grid (e.g. with 0.25 spacing), but where each point on the regularly spaced grid has some tolerance of e.g. +/- 0.05, in order to accommodate irregularities in the real data. Thus allowing me to find those points which sit within this tolerance, at those regularly spaced points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be going about this slightly backwards. Instead of trying to find a tolerance that works (that `1.07871321` really throws things off, doesn't it), just find the point that is closest to your grid points.

Here is a non-looping approach that is wasteful of memory because it creates a full `idxx.size`-by-`n` array, where `n` is the size of your grid:

```
def grid_filter(idxx, spacing):
    # use idxx[0] instead of idxx.min() if idxx is sorted
    g0 = np.floor(idxx.min() / spacing) * spacing
    # use idxx[-1] instead of idxx.max() if idxx is sorted
    g1 = np.ceil(idxx.max() / spacing) * spacing
    # turn the grid into a column vector for broadcasting
    n = np.round((g1 - g0) / spacing) + 1
    grid = np.linspace(g0, g1, n).reshape(-1, 1)

    # compute the absolute distance to each point and
    # get the index of the point nearest each grid point:
    # rows are grid points, columns data points
    indices = np.abs(grid - idxx).argmin(axis=1)
    # post-process to ensure that a data point only matches one grid point
    indices = np.unique(indices)

    # apply the result
    return idxx[indices]
```

The wasteful array is `grid - idxx`. It's probably not going to be an issue. The result of `grid_filter(idxx, 0.25)` is:

```
[ 0. 0.24366872 0.49555099 0.74743326 1.07871321 1.58247775 2.24503765 2.58179329 3.16221766 3.74811773 4.1615332 4.58042437 5.33059548]
```

If you are unhappy with `3.16` and `4.16` making it into the result, you can make the tolerance 1/3 of `spacing` or something similar and work with that:

```
def tolerance_filter(idxx, spacing, tolerance):
    deltas = (idxx % spacing)
    deltas = np.minimum(deltas, spacing - deltas)
    candidates = deltas <  tolerance * spacing
    return idxx[candidates]
```

This solution actually does what you want, and is fully vectorized. `tolerance_filter(idxx, 0.25, 0.33)` returns

```
[ 0. 0.07665982 0.24366872 0.49555099 0.74743326 1.07871321 1.58247775 2.24503765 2.58179329 3.74811773 4.58042437 5.33059548]
```

To further get rid of `0.07665982`, I'd recommend combining the approaches: first filter to get the closest element to each grid point, then filter for absolute tolerance:

```
tolerance_filter(grid_filter(idxx, 0.25), 0.25, 0.33)
```

You could do something even better at this point: first attach each array element to the nearest grid point, as in the first part. Then do some adaptive stuff. For example, get the standard deviation of the residuals, and discard anything above say 3-sigma away from nominal:

```
def sigma_filter(idxx, spacing, nsigma):
    deltas = (idxx % spacing)
    deltas[deltas > 0.5 * spacing] -= spacing
    sigma = np.std(deltas)
    candidates = (np.abs(deltas) <= nsigma * sigma)
    return idxx[candidates]
```

Comment: That is beautiful. But I am curious now then, because you have two points in your results, for 0.25, that I do not consider (and this is subjective, given my domain knowledge) to be 'close' to the regular grid points, namely: 3.16221766 and 4.1615332 (their modulus w.r.t. to 0.25 is just too high). You can see that I did not include these either in my idealised answer in the question. How do we accommodate this in your approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly manage the `+/-` . A simple way to do that :

```
error=minimum(-idxx%.25,idxx%.25)
res= idxx[error<.05]
# [ 0.,  0.24366872,  0.49555099,  0.74743326,  2.24503765, 3.74811773]
```

Comment: isclose manages that just fine. The issue is the imprecise definition of tolerance